# Get lat/lon point of intersection a route and a polygon object on google maps

Tags: polygon, google-maps, intersection

I have a shape (polygon object) and a route, such as on the attached google map.

How I get waypoint (lat/lon, C point on map) where intersect the route and the polygon object?

[image: I need lat/lon point C]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Which GIS software are you using?  Please [edit] your question to include your GIS software and version, and info about what you've tried.

Comment: I sorry, I added google maps for gis software.